# Convolutional Neural Net Architecture - correct?

Tags: python, architecture, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I am trying to train a convolutional neural net. Therefore I am using a datset of 646 images/license plates which contains 8 characters (0-9, A-Z; without letter 'O' and blank spaces, in total 36 possible characters). These are my training data `X_train`. Their shape is `(646, 40, 200, 3)` with color code 3. I resized them to the same shape.

I also have a dataset which contains the labels of this images, which I one-hot-encoded to a numpy array of shape `(646, 8, 36)`. This data is my `y_train` data.

Now, I am trying to apply a Neural Network which looks like this:
[image: Architecture]
The architecture is taken from this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8078501

I excluded the batch normalization part, because this part is not the most interesting one for me. But I am very unsure regarding the top of the layer. That means the part after the last pooling layer beginning with `model.add(Flatten())`...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape = (40, 200, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16000, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(36, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(8*36, activation="Softmax"))
model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((8, 36)))
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the image below matches your model architecture, the code can be used to create the model. Ensure you have some padding for the input images.

[image: Model Architecture]

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Input, Reshape, Concatenate

def create_model(input_shape = (40, 200, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape = (40, 200, 3), activation = "relu")(input_img)
    model = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(model)
    model = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(model)
    model = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation = "relu")(model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(model)
    backbone = Flatten()(model)

    branches = []
    for i in range(8):
        branches.append(backbone)
        branches[i] = Dense(16000, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
        branches[i] = Dense(128, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_128")(branches[i])
        branches[i] = Dense(36, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
    
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((8, 36))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How computationally expensive is such a model to train?

Comment: I have a similar question here, it is also bountied. I assume the architecture would be very similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695857/configuration-of-cnn-model-for-recognition-of-sequential-data-architecture-of/62756783#62756783

Comment: The model seems quite large. Especially the flatten layer that leads to 16,000*8 fully connected nodes. It will require quite a bit of GPU memory for effective training.

Comment: OK, thank you! I don't think such a big number is necessary for my project. One additional question: For the model you described above, we need to use the Functional API and the `Sequential model`, correct?

Comment: Yeah this does use the Sequential Model defined in keras. Just a different way of coding it.

Comment: In the original model, there is batch normalization (bn) mentioned. Could we add bn after each Conv2D layer? If yes, how would you do this?