# Configuration of CNN model for recognition of sequential data - Architecture of the top of the CNN - Parallel Layers

Tags: python, architecture, conv-neural-network

I am trying to configure a network for character recognition of sequential data like license plates.
Now I would like to use the architecture which is noted in Table 3 in Deep Automatic Licence Plate Recognition system (link: http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/people/faculty/soma.biswas/Papers/jain_icgvip2016_alpr.pdf).

The architecture the authors presented is this one:

[image: CNN]

The first layers are very common, but where I was stumbling was the top (the part in the red frame) of the architecture. They mention 11 parallel layers and I am really unsure how to get this in Python. I coded this architecture but it does not seem to be right to me.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape = (32, 96, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(11*37, activation="Softmax"))
model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((11, 37)))
```

Could someone help? How do I have to code the top to get an equal architecture like the authors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below can build the architecture described in the image.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Input, Reshape, Concatenate, Dropout

def create_model(input_shape = (32, 96, 1)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    '''
    Add the ST Layer here.
    '''
    model = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape = input_shape, activation = "relu")(input_img)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)

    model = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape = input_shape, activation = "relu")(model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)

    model = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape = input_shape, activation = "relu")(model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(model)
    model = Dropout(0.25)(model)

    model = Flatten()(model)
    backbone = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(model)

    branches = []
    for i in range(11):
        branches.append(backbone)
        branches[i] = Dense(37, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i))(branches[i])
    
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((11, 37))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model
```

[image: Model Architecture]

Comment: This model seems to be much easier to train than the other one. I am wondering about this because they both achieved similar accuracy on similar tasks..

Comment: The input image size will mostly be responsible for that. Since the input image is smaller here, the model can be more shallow and simple and still provide the same accuracy.

Comment: How could I apply such a model to my data? Could I use `model.fit_generator`?

Comment: Yes you can use `model.fit_generator` or just `model.fit` since the functionality has been updated to behave the same way and `model.fit_generator` is deprecated.

Comment: How do I get a picture as the one you posted?

Comment: https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/

Save the model architecture as a `.json` file and load into Netron.

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, your implementation is almost correct. The authors train 11 individual classifiers taking as input the output from the Fully Connected Layer. Here, you can think of "parallel" as "independent".

However, you cannot apply the Softmax activation right after the Fully Connected Layer. Since all the classifiers are independent, we want each of them to output a probability for each possible character. Putting things differently, we want the sum of the outputs of each classifier to be 1. Hence, the correct implementation would be:

```py
...
model.add(Dense(1024, activation = "relu"))
# Feeding every neuron with the previous layer's output
model.add(Dense(11*37))
model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((11, 37)))
model.add(keras.activations.softmax(x, axis=1))
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! Would you mind, taking a look to this very similar question? It is also bountied and I think the architecture I am looking for in this question is very similar and could maybe confirm your answer here. That would be more than great! I am also willing to give you both bounties but I would be more than glad if you could re-check your answer by taking a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521042/convolutional-neural-net-architecture-correct